# relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import an class into my test (test_account.py), but I get the following error:

```
from ..src.account_status import TestClass
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is my directory I have scr and test in the same App directory.

```
./App/src/account_status.py
./App/test/test_account.py
```

My import in test_account.py:

```
from ..src.account_status import TestClass
```

I have tried adding `__init__.py` to both folders and the App directory, but I get the same message, why?

Comment: You wrote `src` in the file but the directory is called `scr`.

Comment: Cope and Paste error, sorry. I have updated and have the same issue.

Comment: Because you're not running the module from the package root. Try `python -m test.test_account`

Comment: I'm running like this `python -m unittest discover -s /User/App/ -p 'test_*.py'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../src")
from account_status import TestClass
sys.path.remove("../src")
```